# If Else On Php Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php
$genre = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'genre', '<span class="genre">', ', ', '</span>');
$tags = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'tag-series-movies','<span class="genre">', ', ', '</span>');

if($genre,$tags)
    echo '<li>Genre: '. $genre . '</li>';
    echo '<li>Tags: '. $genre . '</li>';
else {
    echo '';
}
?>
```

Hi. Guys whats wrong of my code? though the code is working 50%. the $genre is working but the else is not working. please help. i want to show the nothing when no genres is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `if($genre == $genre)` to `if($genre){`

`get_the_term_list` returns the list or false so you just need to check that `$genre` is a truthy value

In your current code when `$genre` is false you are checking `if(false == false)` which always returns true

EDIT:

you can simplify your code like this

```
if($genre){
    echo '<li>Genre: '. $genre . '</li>';
}
if($tags){
    echo '<li>Tags: '. $tags . '</li>';
}
```

There's no need for the else statement as you're not echoing anything

Comment: If my answer helped you please mark as the correct answer and/or upvote

Comment: Ok i will accept it after 5 mins bro. bro how can i if else on two variable in the right way? i updated the code.